# How to restore mongo base from local folder to uri

Tags: database, mongodb, database-backups, database-restore

i use following code but Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
How can i restore database from local folder to mondogb prod server with uri?

```
mongorestore -h 10.10.10.10 --port 27017 -d test_base -u myusername -p mypassword C:\My profile\Documents\mongo\test_base
```

Comment: The path contains space characters, enclose it in quotes (`"`)

Comment: Hi my friend. I cant understand what i must do?! please explain me

Comment: Try `"C:\My profile\Documents\mongo\test_base"`

Comment: retrieved: 

2020-04-29T15:31:42.398+0400    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Answer (score 0):

The mongo tools have two database options:

- `--db=<database>, -d=<database>`

  Specifies the destination database for mongorestore to restore data into when restoring from a BSON file.
- `--authenticationDatabase=<dbname>`

  Specifies a password with which to authenticate to a MongoDB database that uses authentication.

Authentication database is usually `admin`, however it defaults to destination database, if provided. The mongo documentation is not 100% clear regarding this topic. You should always specify both in order to avoid any conflicts.

Then check the syntax. Options can be provided like

- `/u myusername`
- `-u myusername`
- `-u=myusername`
- `/username:myusername`
- `--username:myusername`
- `--username=myusername`

Unfortunately is is not clear which one is valid (or which ones are valid). When you run  `mongorestore --help` at Linux and Windows and have a look at [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/), you see it is not consistent.

Do "try and error"

Comment: Thanks can i do it with URI?

Comment: Thankx i did it! Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, you can put all this into an URI. Have a look at the linked documentation